# How to align objects on different lines horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to start an exercise

1. by a number (I.1 or XII.32)
2. then some space
3. and then the beginning of the exercise
   so that **all the beginnings of the exercises (point 3. above) are horizontally aligned**, as in the following picture.

[image]

Exercises belong to different paragraphs and may have several lines and centered formulas.

How can I align the beginning of the exercises of a same page?

Comment: `\makebox[3cm][l]{II.2}{Zzzzz}` and `\makebox[3cm][l]{XIII.32}{Zzzzz}` ?

Comment: One could also use a table without visible lines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was thinking of a command but I can't remember its name. It's a command that allows someone to write words on the top one of the other; it's a command that allows someone to "come back at the beginning of a line".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\hbox to2cm{...} ...`

Use `\leavevmode` to leave vertical mode and switch to horizontal mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\leavevmode\hbox to2cm{\textbf{I.1}} First exercise 

\leavevmode\hbox to2cm{\textbf{XII.13}} Last exercise
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a list rather than setting each exercise manually. You can use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to format the list setting globally (like I did below by creating an `exercises` list):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{
  labelwidth=2cm,
  font=\bfseries,
  align=left
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercises}
  \item[I.1]
    First exercise 

  \item[IX.78]
    \lipsum[1]
    
  \item[XII.13]
    Last exercise
\end{exercises}

\end{document}
```